# Tkinter Label is give me random tabbing of text when using \n

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a label from python's Tkinter that will store information eventually. Right now I'm just using a place holder but it's tabbing in the text when I enter the text down with \n.

What the Label looks like with the current code:
[Tkinter Label without the text correctly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uc1e.png)

And here's the code which is used to make the label:

```
StoryFrame = LabelFrame(root, width = 1000, heigh = 300, bg="DarkGrey", highlightbackground='black', text='Current News in Technology', font="Helvetica 15 bold")

StoryFrame.place(relx=0.03, rely= 0.65)

info = Label(StoryFrame, anchor=NW, text="Dateline: Date and/or time\n\nNews source: Name\n\nHostname: Domain\n\nURL: Address", width=40, height=17)

info.place(relx=0.685, rely= 0.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the default value of `justify` option is "center".  If you want to align the lines at the left, add `justify="left"` in `Label()`:

```py
info = Label(StoryFrame, anchor=NW,
             text="Dateline: Date and/or time\n\nNews source: Name\n\nHostname: Domain\n\nURL: Address",
             width=40, height=17, justify="left")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

StoryFrame = LabelFrame(root, width = 1000, heigh = 300, bg="DarkGrey", highlightbackground='black', text='Current News in Technology', font="Helvetica 15 bold")

StoryFrame.place(relx=0.03, rely= 0.65)

info = Label(StoryFrame, anchor=NW, text="Dateline: Date and/or time\n\nNews source: Name\n\nHostname: Domain\n\nURL: Address", width=40, height=17, justify='left')

info.place(relx=0.685, rely= 0.01)

root.mainloop()
```

This code gives the output you want. If have added `justify='left'`  to align it to left.